# Is it possible to select a column while keeping its colname?

Tags: r, indexing, names

I would like to index-select a column from a matrix while keeping is `colname`. For example

```
m<-matrix(1:9,ncol=3)
colnames(m)<-c('V1','V2','V3')
selected<-as.matrix(m[,1])
```

However,

```
> selected
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

I would like to have `colname(selected)<-'V1'` as a result instead. Why does R behave like this and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `as.matrix()` in the last line and use `drop=FALSE` (see `?Extract`)

```
> m<-matrix(1:9,ncol=3)
> colnames(m)<-c('V1','V2','V3')
> m[,1,drop=FALSE]
     V1
[1,]  1
[2,]  2
[3,]  3
```

What you do, is selecting a single column. R will by default drop all dimensions (and hence also the names) that are not necessary. In this case, you drop one dimension as a single column can be seen as a vector. The argument `drop=FALSE` prevents this.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the `drop` argument.